# Could DC-10s be equipped with seatback inflight entertainment screens, given that the oxygen systems are in seatbacks rather than overhead?

Tags: inflight-entertainment, oxygen-mask, dc-10

Unlike most passenger aircraft, the supplemental oxygen mask system on the McDonnell Douglas DC-10 [was located in the backs of passenger seats](https://youtu.be/R37pftDR9Ss?t=452), rather than in an overhead compartment in the passenger service unit.

However, this seems to me like it wouldn't be possible to equip DC-10 aircraft with seatback inflight entertainment screens, since there'd be no space in the seatback headrest to hold the required electronics for a display screen as it'd all be taken up by the oxygen system.

I've seen [this video](https://youtu.be/xKfHQ5cOEh0?t=55), which shows seatback screens on an MD-11, which I think is simply a stretched DC-10, and looking closely I think the supplemental oxygen is located in the standard spot, overhead in the passenger service unit. I think the position must have changed for the MD-11 aircraft.

Was it possible for airlines to equip the DC-10 with seatback IFE screens? Was there an option to have oxygen masks in the standard overhead spot? Or did no airline ever equip their DC-10 with seatback screens?

Comment: Given that the DC-10 has been out of passenger operations for over 7 years this question is moot, I would say that anything is possible with enough engineering. It would probably be far easier to just give people tablets and collect them at the end of the flight.

Comment: I’m reading this question on my iPad.  It is about the same size as a seat back screen, and roughly a quarter of an inch thick.  Do you think the seats could be made a quarter inch thicker if it was absolutely needed to accommodate both?  I don’t have an answer for you, but it is entirely believable that both might fit.

Comment: Have you seen how thin tablets and laptop screens are?  Why would you think they couldn’t be used as the flip-down covers shown in the video?

Comment: @Jim Modern tablets use LED backlights. But back when the DC-10 was in service and IFEs were installed, LED-backlit screens were super expensive, and that extra cost would add up when installing 200+ screens. As such most other aircraft types' IFEs used the much cheaper but thicker and heavier fluorescent light backlights. Also, you'd need quite a bit of cabling to connect the touchscreen to the IFE box under the seat. As such, I don't think it was viable to put IFEs in the seatbacks, though I could be wrong.

Comment: @MichaelHall See above.

Comment: @gparyani - I guess I misunderstood your question. It asks “Could DC-10s be equipped” not “Could DC-10 have been equipped”.  From that I assumed you meant today not back then.

Comment: @Jim Yeah, I meant "could" as the past tense of "can".

Comment: “Could have”, or the shortened “could’ve” (never “could of”…) is past tense for can.  “Could” alone is more aligned with “possible”.  But I got your point…

Comment: @GdD You should make this your answer. I think this one should be accepted as correct.